# Remote Desktop from Windows machine using something other than Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, xorg, remote-desktop, rdp

Ubuntu 12.04.3

I have a question regarding a computer I use as a file server on my home network. The hardware is actually an old Asus netbook (don't laugh, it's low power, silent, and has a built in backup power supply). I originally used the machine as a normal workstation but when the keyboard went I started using it as a server.

I used tasksel to remove "Ubuntu Desktop." due to it's high resource usage. I mostly access the machine using SSH, but now that I have removed Unity I miss being able to use a remote desktop.

Is there a way that I can set up a graphical desktop to use remotely from my Windows machine that will be less intensive than Unity? I would prefer, if possible, that the computer itself doesn't show anything on the screen while I am using it remotely. There is a driver bug that doesn't allow me to close the lid without the system going to sleep, so being able to have the screen be blank while i'm remotely using a graphical desktop  would be great.

Any ideas, oh great community of Linux intellectuals? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go a little crazy and re installed the whole system with debian instead of Ubuntu and now I'm using LXDE via VNC. Problem solved.